# Most elegant way to serialize an object with byte[] members to an XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a serialization utility that serializes an object to an XDocument. It works quite well :

```
public static class SerializationUtil
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(XDocument doc)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (var reader = doc.Root.CreateReader())
        {
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public static XDocument Serialize<T>(T value)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        XDocument doc = new XDocument(z);
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

        return doc;
    }
```

Been using it quite happily and suddenly I get :

```
There was an error generating the XML document.
```

The inner exception is :

```
This XmlWriter does not support base64 encoded data.
```

Turns out that the `XDocument.CreateWriter()` instance method gives you a writer of type `System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter`, and that that writer can't write base64 encoded data (my object contains a byte[]).

MSDN doesn't even seem to mention this class - but I can't seem to create any other type of writer from `XDocument`.

I could just serialize to a string, but i was trying to be clever and avoid using any hacks. Any way to serialize to XDocument when base64 is needed for certain fields.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882.aspx), there's no allowance for bytes.  A surrogate base64 encoded string property is probably your best bet (is it a hack if its by design?).

Comment: ah ok - i just assumed any valid XML could be supported. i just wish the XmlSerializer was cleverer enough to handle it for me. i'll just revert back to serializing to a StringWriter which works fine

Comment: but shouldnt the xmlserializer be responsible for the conversion? after all xml is all just text anyway.

Comment: The serializer _is_ converting it, but the `XmlWriter` from the `XDocument` doesn't like its conversion -- that's the error you're getting.  There may be other XmlWriters that don't have the same problem -- for example, instead of using an `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`, you might have better luck with using `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

Comment: Alternatively, you have to work around the restrictions, by restricting your type to only have properties that work well... which, in this case, means not serializing the byte array directly.